# ProtocolLogger with multiple threads

Tags: c#, vb.net, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit with threads , everything is fine so far but i'm trying to save logs to read it and check if something went wrong, but i get this error

> The process cannot access the file 'smtp.log' because it is being used
> by another process.

I understand the reason behind the error , you can't use same file with multiple threads
, you need to use (SyncLock) etc...

but the issue is that's the syntax

```
ProtocolLogger(
    string fileName,
    bool append = true
)
```

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_ProtocolLogger__ctor_1.htm

Code Example: C#

```
    using (var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log", TRUE))) {

    client.Connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    etc.....
}
```

VB.net

```
       Using client = New SmtpClient(New ProtocolLogger("smtp.log", True))
            '  
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect)

            client.Authenticate(login, pass)
```

Is there's anyway to get around it and write data to ***smtp.log*** without getting the error or using ***SyncLock*** with ***ProtocolLogger***client ?

Comment: I added C# tag since i can translate to vb.net

Comment: The file is being used by another application.  Restart computer and try again.  The error message may be wrong and the issue is you cannot open the file.  Try including a full pathname and see if you still get same error.

Comment: The [source for ProtocolLogger](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/ProtocolLogger.cs) is available on GitHub. It appears to me that if you create the line to be logged in a StringBuilder instead of using lots of stream.Write calls and then pass that string to a thread-safe writer (as I posted an example to in a comment on your previous question) where it uses stream.Flush, you would be able to make it thread-safe.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i don't understand you , how i will be able to make that

Comment: @AndrewMorton you suggesting that i edit the sourcecode right ?

Comment: @hewman Yes, take a copy of the source code and modify it. (Read the copyright notice at the top.) Or you could contact the author and ask if perhaps they have a thread-safe version.

Comment: @hewman Oh, hang on, have you tried it with just one instance of ProtocolLogger instead of making a new instance for each thread?

Comment: Was this resolved? I encountered similar issue and its not being resolved.

I am using client.Dispose() at the end so that it disposes all the resources used.

Still after invoking the func on the next iteration, it errors out saying file in use.